# how to control content sizing in bootstrap column grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap grid inside the columns, I have a card with an image in it, but my card does not occupy the full width of my column, how do I make it possible?

[My column right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWmxX.png)

I've tried playing with the width of the card but it seems there's some maximum limit to the grid size or for some grid sizes, other elements on the page are effected.

```
div class="container2">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- outer grid first column -->
            <div class="col-8">
                MODULES
                <div class="module-container">
                    <!-- first column inner grid  -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <img src="images/GC.png" class="img-top img-responsive fit-image" alt="module 1" >
                          GC   
                          </div>
```

CSS

```
    .fit-image{
  width: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 300px; /* only if you want fixed height */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want fit your image to the full width of the column then u can use some css

```
your code goes here
..........
<img src="images/GC.png" class="card-img-top img-responsive fit-image" alt="module 1" >
.........
```

add css like this

```
.fit-image{
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
height: 300px; /* only if you want fixed height */
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and right now it fits the height but not the width, ive tried change the width properties but it wouldn't go above that width

Comment: @croob27 try this code   img{ width:100%; }